# Please explain an issue with python generator

Tags: python, loops, iteration, generator

I'am currently studying Python and recently encountered Python generators. I think I'm getting the idea of it, but this code (a little function to yield prime numbers):

```
import math
def prime_num():
    num = 2
    while num < 20:
        sq = math.ceil(num**1/2)
        for i in range(2, sq+1):
            if num % i == 0:
                break
            else: 
                yield num
        num += 1
pr = prime_num()
for i in pr:
    print(i)
```

Outputs this:

```
3
5 
5 
7 
7 
7 
9 
11
11
11
11
11
13
13
13
13
13
13
15
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
```

Can somebody explain why are there multiple copies of a single int?

Comment: I think the else belongs to the for loop and not the if expression

Comment: oh, it works now.. feel a bit stupid now haha

Comment: didn't know u can do for/else block, need to work on that one, thank you @DaniMesejo

Comment: Think about the placement of the `yield` statement.  Pop in a couple `print` statements to debug the progress.  You’ll realise what’s happening.

Comment: @S3DEV It was all about the else statement, popping print statements everywhere is what I do every single day now haha, thank you for the advice ;)

Comment: @zetta `while` and `try` also support an `else` case, just so you know.

Comment: yeah I just didn't know `while` and `for` support `else`